# Error 404con editor de textos e ASP.NET alsubir imagenes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp, error404

Tengo en mi web un editor de textos, como un plugin de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay un icono para poder subir archivos que lo que hace es ir a una ruta del sistema donde estan almacenadas las imagenes, documentos, etc. Bien. Antes funcionaba perfecto, pero desde hace meses (creo que desde que cambiamos de servidor), no funciona y me da el siguiente error cuando pinchas en el icono.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como lo podria solucionar?

Un saludo y muchas grtacias de antemano,.

Comment: Has comprobado si esa ruta en donde apuntas existe?

Comment: Hola. Sí claro, esa ruta existe. Como digo antes funcionaba pero ahora nada. Un saludo.